# Get past values from streams

Tags: stream, dart

Is it possible to get the last added value or previous values from a `StreamController.broadcast` / `Stream`.

Basically I have some subscriptions to streams like `on('data')` and `on('ready')` and I want for example that if someone listens to `on('ready')` after the event was triggered they can get the last value from the broadcast stream, eg. `'I\'m ready'`.

Something like:

```
StreamController x = StreamController.broadcast();

first = x.first.then(doSomething);
x.add('oneOffEvent');
// first ~ 'oneOffEvent'
x.close()
other = x.last.then(doSomethingElse);
// other ~ 'oneOffEvent'
```

Is this even possible without caching the value somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast Streams, by design, do not wait for subscriptions to fire events.

You can, however, do both a first and last subscription before adding events.

Add many subscriptions. That's the upside of broadcast subscriptions.